# If $x$ is a limit point of $A$, then $x$ is a limit point of $U \cap A$

Tags: general-topology

> $x$ is a limit point of $A$, and $U$ is an open subset containing $x$. Show that $x$ is a limit point of $A \cap U$.

I feel like this might be easy/obvious but I can't seem to get it. I tried considering the definition so what we want to prove is $((A \cap U) - x) \cap V$ must be nonempty for all open neighborhoods $V$ containing $x$. I know that $(A-x) \cap V \neq \emptyset$ and $(A-x) \cap U \neq \emptyset$, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is an open set containing $x$ then so is $U \cap V$. Hence $(U\cap V) \cap (A\setminus \{x\}$ is non-empty. This implies that $(A\cap U \setminus \{x\}) \cap V$ is non-empty.